# Why doesn't this "recursive" way of adding eventlisteners work?

Tags: javascript

I thought this would work out perfectly but somehow it doesn't:

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('#menu_btn');

let transitionIn = e => {
    menu.classList.add("transitionIn");
    menuBtn.addEventListener('click', transitionOut);
}

let transitionOut = e => {
    menu.classList.remove("transitionIn");
    menuBtn.addEventListener('click', transitionIn);
}

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', transitionIn)
```

What could be wrong in my code?

Comment: Adding an event listener does not remove previously-added event listeners.

Comment: See `removeEventListener`!

Comment: event listeners are called all together are you trying to switch between add remove class ?

Comment: Oh, so I just have to remove it in order for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the issue and if I understand correctly you are really complicating life for yourself.

Assuming you try to toggle between two classes on click you could write something like the snippet I added which does not require you to create multiple event listeners continuously

```js
const foo = document.querySelector("#foo");
foo.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (foo.classList.contains("transition-in")) {
    foo.classList.remove("transition-in")
    foo.classList.add("transition-out")
  } else {
    foo.classList.add("transition-in")
    foo.classList.remove("transition-out")
  }
})
```

```css
.transition-in {
  background-color: red;
}

.transition-out {
  background-color: blue;
}

#foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add removeEventListener!